# Android how to compose notification on notification bar

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to now how to create a notification in the notification bar and compose it like 'usb connected' or 'usb debugging connected' notify. Can anyone help me with some codes?

Comment: Did you read the [Guide on notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) from the official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I have used   NotificationCompat.Builder for the purpose

First we have to style the notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // icon to be displayed
                .setContentTitle("Notification") // title for the notification
                .setContentText(msg); // msg is some text you want to display
```

For Led light blinkering when notification is received

```
mBuilder.setLights(Color.BLUE,1000,1200);
```

To give notification sound you can make use of default notification sound set by the user

```
Uri sound=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); 
mBuilder.setSound(sound);
```

To cancel the notification when the user has selected it

```
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

To start an activity in app when the user clicks the notification

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, resultIntent,0);           
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Finally to show the notification in the bar make use of notification manager

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Can I use getText() and put in setContentTitle? like a battery widget or chalander..